# How to combine a 2D array into one, using a pre-defined method that only takes 2 arrays at a time?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, concatenation

I'm working on an interview practice question where we're given a 2d array (arr[16][64], so 16 arrays with 64 elements each). We're first asked to sort each array, and then combine them into one big sorted array, using the given methods (without creating any new methods).

The given method for combining takes only **two** arrays, merges them, and returns a single combined array. It's a very straightforward function, no libraries or anything like that, just plain Java code.

I was able to sort the 16 arrays, but I can't figure out how to use the given combine() function to merge/combine all 16 arrays. The only thing I could think to do was

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        finalArray = combine(2dArray[i], 2dArray[i+1]);
    }
```

but of course that's only combining 2 arrays. Where should I go from here?

Comment: What is the code for "combine"? Or, where can we look up the API?

Comment: 2dArray is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Not a good way to do it but, you could try something like `finalArray = combine (array2d[0], combine (array2d[1], combine (array2d[2],  combine(array2d[3], ... ))))))))))))))));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your problem statement the following should work:

```
int[] finalArray = new int[0];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    finalArray = combine(finalArray, 2dArray[i]);
}
return finalArray;
```

The invariant for this loop is that `finalArray` is always sorted. So, at the end you will have one big sorted array in this variable.

**P.S.** Using the OP's original `2dArray` variable name in the code snippet. However, it's not a valid name in Java because you can't start a variable name with a number.

Comment: Suggestion:  `for (int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++)` makes it more flexible.  (I used a different name for  `2dArray` because it's not a valid variable name.)